# How does exshuffle works in cloze questions (package `exams`)?

Tags: r, r-exams

I would like to understand how does `exsuffle` works on `cloze` questions. Does it work with various `schoice` questions with a different number of possible answers?

I expect to have the possible answers shuffled when presenting the exercises in Moodle. With the observed behavior, the order is always the same.

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you don't understand. Maybe you can provide the Rmd (or Rnw) code for a simple artificial cloze question with two schoice parts? And please describe which behavior you would expect but don't get.

Comment: I added information.

Comment: I did this workaround:

```
options[[1]] <- sample(paste0(c(correct_answer, possible_answers[!possible_answers %in% correct_answer])))
solutions[[1]] <- options[[1]]==correct_answer
```

Comment: I just checked the shuffle code and it also worked for `cloze` questions provided that a solutionlist was also provided. I now fixed the latter part in the devel version. Could you please run `install.packages("exams", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` and try again? If it still doesn't work, please provide the source code for a minimal, self-contained `cloze` exercise.

Comment: It's working with this new devel version. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for testing! As already pointed out in the comments of another questions: This would have been easier to detect if you had posted a minimal reproducible example, i.e., in this case the code for a concrete simplified exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you can use (for future reference) "MULTICHOICE_VS" as in:

```
    exams2moodle(questions,
             name = "exameXPTO", 
             cloze = list(cloze_mchoice_display = "MULTICHOICE_VS"), 
             envir =.GlobalEnv)
```

:-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I added the availability of the shuffled `MULTICHOICE` and `MULTIRESPONSE` variants on `?exams2moodle` now. Note, however, that this only corresponds to `exshuffle` being `TRUE` but not a numeric value.

Comment: Thank you Achim and team, for the great exams package and the countless hours you spend helping us!

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm learning a lot through these interactions as well. In contrast to classical software engineering that you do for a specific (group of) customer(s) it's not always easy to know what users of open-source software like R/exams need/expect/struggle with/etc. Hence, discussions like this improve the software quite a bit!

Answer (score 3):

The `exshuffle` option in the meta-information for R/exams questions also works for `schoice` or `mchoice` elements within `cloze` questions. Notes:

- *Bug fix:* Prior to R/exams version 2.4-0 specifying `exshuffle` in `cloze` question without an answer list in the solution part of the exercise lead to an error. This prompted this StackOverflow question but has been fixed now.
- Numeric values for `exshuffle` (i.e., sub-sampling a larger number of answer alternatives) also work.
- Instead of setting `exshuffle` to `TRUE` which does the shuffling on the R side, it is also possible to do the shuffling in Moodle (as pointed out by @JPMD) by selecting a `cloze_mchoice_display` that includes shuffling, e.g., `MULTICHOICE_S` or `MULTICHOICE_VS` etc..
- Currently, only a single `exshuffle` value can currently be set for the entire question. Thus, if there are multiple `schoice` and/or `mchoice` elements, this single `exshuffle` value is applied to all of them.

Answer (score 2):

````
```
options[[1]] <- sample(paste0(c(correct_answer, possible_answers[!possible_answers %in% correct_answer])))
solutions[[1]] <- options[[1]]==correct_answer
```
````

Comment: Yes, doing the shuffling yourself in the R code rather than relying on the `exshuffle` option in R/exams is always a solution.